# On an identity between the inverse metric and the Laplace-Beltrami Operator

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, tensors, heat-equation

Consider the anisotropic heat equation in $\mathbb{R}^n$: $$ \partial_tu=\partial_i(g^{ij}\partial_j u) $$
where $\displaystyle \partial_i = \partial_{x_i}$ and $g^{ij}$ are the components of the inverse of some metric tensor.

I want to ask when we also have: $$ \partial_t u = \Delta_g u $$ whenever the first equation holds.

---

I can do this if $\det(g)=|g|$ is constant:
\begin{align}
\partial_tu 
&= \partial_i(g^{ij}\partial_j u)\\
&= \partial_ig^{ij}\partial_j u + g^{ij}\partial_{ij}u\\[1mm]
&= \sqrt{|g|}^{-1}\partial_i\left(\sqrt{|g|}g^{ij}\right)\partial_j u + g^{ij}\partial_{ij}u \\
&= \sqrt{|g|}^{-1}\left[ -\sqrt{|g|}g^{i\ell}\Gamma^j_{i\ell} \right]  \partial_j u + g^{ij}\partial_{ij}u \\
&= \Delta_g u
\end{align}

where I used the identities:
$$
g^{i\ell}\Gamma^j_{i\ell}=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{|g|}}\partial_i\left(g^{ji}\sqrt{|g|}\right)
$$ $$ \Delta_g = g^{jk}\partial_{jk} - g^{jk}\Gamma_{jk}^\ell\partial_\ell $$
Or, as I just realized, more easily, using the identity: $\Delta_g=\sqrt{|g|}^{-1}\partial_i(\sqrt{|g|}g^{ij}\partial_j) $.

---

Does this hold in other cases?

Comment: The last formula in your question tells you this is true if and only if $\sqrt{|g|}^{-1}(\partial_i \sqrt{|g|}g^{ij})\partial_j u = 0$, or $(\partial_i g)g^{ij} \partial_i u = 0$ after differentiating. This, or its various other forms, hold in general if the [harmonic gauge condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_coordinate_condition) holds.

Comment: @Chappers Thanks for your comment! One confusion: the harmonic gauge condition appears to be on the coordinates rather than the metric. Is this the case? I would have expected this property to be invariant to the coordinate system.

Comment: Of course, the metric also depends on the coordinates (at least in that it changes as a $(0,2)$-tensor under change of coordinates). Actually, I think I've got this slightly wrong: your condition reduces to $(\partial_i g)g^{ij}\partial_j u$, which is a bit different.

Comment: If the latter is to hold for any $u$, then we have to have $\partial_i g=0$, so $g$ is constant, but if it's only a few particular $u$s, there could be nonconstant examples.

Comment: @Chappers What do you mean $g$ is constant? Do you mean $|g|$?

Comment: I mean the determinant. It depends if $|g|$ means the determinant of the metric or the absolute value of that determinant. It's normal to denote the determinant by simply $g$.

Comment: @Chappers Ah sorry... I always see $\det(g)=|g|=G$ as the determinant and $g$ as the matrix/function/bilinear form... oh the notation in this field :) ... in any case, thank you. Basically, you are saying that for general $u$ you *need* $\partial_j \det(g)=0\;\forall\;j$ i.e. $\det(g)$ being constant.

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can see that:
$$
\Delta_g u= g^{ij}\partial_{ij} u + 
\left( g^{ij}\partial_i\sqrt{|g|}+\partial_i g^{ij} \right)\partial_j u
$$
So we have $$ \Delta_g u = g^{ij}\partial_{ij}u+\partial_i g^{ij}\partial_j u $$
only if $$ g^{ij}\partial_i\sqrt{|g|}\partial_j u =0 $$
Clearly, this is true if $|g|$ is constant.

Just to expand this a bit, we see that it is equivalent to
$$ \frac{1}{2}g^{ij}\sqrt{|g|}\;\text{tr}(g^{-1}\partial_i g)\partial_j u = 0 $$
using the formula for the derivative of a determinant.

Anyone who has an interpretation for this is welcome to comment on it.